# unordered_map with forbidden collisions

Tags: c++, optimization, hash, std

I want to implement a performance-optimized variant of `unordered_map` that works in several phases:

1. Initialization: Insert about 100 elements into `std::map`
2. Preparation: Do some magic, converting `std::map` to a variant of `std::unordered_map`
3. Work: Perform a large (unbounded) number of lookups; insertions/deletions are forbidden

In order to make the "work" phase as fast as possible, i would like to choose a hashing function that has no collisions for the given set of keys (gathered at initialization phase).

I would like to measure how much performance improvement i can get from this trick. So this is going to be an experiment, possibly going into production code.

Does the standard library have facilities for this implementation (e.g. finding how many collisions a given `unordered_map` has; or changing a hashing function)? Or should i make my own implementation instead?

Comment: Take a look at gperf to generate perfect hash functions (of course, you will need to hand it *all* of the inputs if you want the hashing to be perfect...)

Comment: I'm fairly sure gperf needs to know the full set of items at compile time.

Comment: What about using an existing method like perfect hashing? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_perfect_hashing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the "collision management" API:

```
size_type bucket_count() const;
size_type max_bucket_count() const;

size_type bucket_size(size_type n) const;
size_type bucket(const key_type& k) const;

local_iterator       begin(size_type n);
local_iterator       end(size_type n);
const_local_iterator begin(size_type n) const;
const_local_iterator end(size_type n) const;
const_local_iterator cbegin(size_type n) const;
const_local_iterator cend(size_type n) const;
```

In a nutshell, `bucket_size(n)` gives you the number of collisions for the nth bucket.  You can look up buckets with a key, and you can iterate over buckets with local_iterator.

For changing a hash function, I would assign/construct a new container, from the old hash function to the new.

Answer (score 2):

If you have many reads and less writes, you could use vector as a map. It is very common, because `lower_bound` is more effective than `map` and use less space from memory:

```
bool your_less_function( const your_type &a, const your_type &b )
{
  // based on keys
  return ( a < b );
}
...
std::vector<your_type> ordered-vector;
```

When you add values:

```
...
// First 100 values
ordered-vector.push_back(value)
...
// Finally. The vector must be sorted before read.
std::sort( ordered-vector.begin(), ordered-vector.end(), your_less_function );
```

When ask for data:

```
std::vector<your_type>::iterator iter = std::lower_bound( ordered-vector.begin(), ordered-vector.end(), value, your_less_function );
if ( ( iter == ordered-vector.end() ) || your_less_function( *iter, value ) )
  // you did not find the value
else
  // iter contains the value
```

Unfortunately it is ordered, but really fast.

Comment: With only 100 entries in the table, the comparisons done by the binary search in `lower_bound` should be pretty quick. A simple hash could still be quicker though.

Answer (score 0):

The number of collisions depends on the number of buckets. Is it useful for you to use the rehash function to set the number of buckets to 100, as per the [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html)?